# How to compute the sum of multiple columns in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I would like to know if there's a way to compute the sum of multiple columns in PostgreSQL.

I have a table with more than 80 columns and I have to write a query that adds each value from each column.

I tried with SUM(col1, col2, col3 etc) but it didn't work.

Comment: You mean a sum per row, or a total sum for all rows?

Comment: I mean a sum per row.

Comment: I just want to clarify further that you did not mean "I want to sum all of column A and then add it to the sum of column B", you meant "In each row, I want to sum the value in column A and the value in column B and store it in the result".

Answer (score 116, accepted):

```
SELECT COALESCE(col1,0) + COALESCE(col2,0)
FROM yourtable
```

Comment: I tried that, but there are columns where there are no values (NULL) and the final result is NULL, so its not ok.

Comment: Answer modified to account for that, and the comment that you're looking for a per-row sum.

Comment: how do I do that with temporary columns that I requested with "AS" ?

Comment: @qqx Can someone explain why we need to use COALESCE here if col1 and col2 are both numeric data types?

Comment: @Bulrush that would be a separate question, and likely one that's already answered.

Comment: It returns nothing, if no rows found for passed `WHERE` condition. I expect `0` in this case... Maybe, this could help: `SELECT COALESCE(SUM(col1), 0) + COALESCE(SUM(col2), 0) FROM yourtable;`.

Answer (score 79):

It depends on how you'd like to sum the values. If I read your question correctly, you are looking for the second SELECT from this example:

```
template1=# SELECT * FROM yourtable ;
 a | b 
---+---
 1 | 2
 4 | 5
(2 rows)

template1=# SELECT a + b FROM yourtable ;
 ?column? 
----------
        3
        9
(2 rows)

template1=# SELECT SUM( a ), SUM( b ) FROM yourtable ;
 sum | sum 
-----+-----
   5 |   7
(1 row)

template1=# SELECT SUM( a + b ) FROM yourtable ;
 sum 
-----
  12
(1 row)

template1=#
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Like the comments in the other answer, I was having trouble with SUM returning NULL so here's a fix if anyone needs: `SELECT GREATEST(0, SUM(a + b)) FROM yourtable;`

Answer (score 18):

Combined the current answers and used this to get total SUM:

```
SELECT SUM(COALESCE(col1,0) + COALESCE(col2,0)) FROM yourtable;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT(
    SELECT SUM(t.f)
    FROM (VALUES (yourtable.col1), (yourtable.col2), (yourtable.col3)) t(f)
)
FROM yourtable;
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works? What would you call `t(f)`?