# Adding all the values of a column if another column matches

Tags: android, sqlite

I created a view to combine two tables( `COMPANY` and `PAYMENTS` ) like so where `COMPANY` comes from `COMPANY` and the `PAYDUE` and `DATEDUE` come from `PAYMENTS`

```
COMPANY | PAYDUE | DATEDUE
```

Now I need to basically sum up ALL the values in `PAYDUE` if their `COMPANY` and `DATEDUE` matches.

So let's say I have these entries:

```
COMPANY | PAYDUE | DATEDUE
Comp 1  | 8000   | 4/30/2015
Comp 1  | 7000   | 5/15/2015
Comp 1  | 6000   | 4/30/2015
Comp 1  | 5000   | 5/15/2015
Comp 2  | 4000   | 4/30/2015
Comp 2  | 3000   | 5/15/2015
Comp 2  | 2000   | 4/30/2015
Comp 2  | 1000   | 5/15/2015
```

What I need is to add the `PAYDUE` of all the rows with identical `COMPANY` and `DATEDUE` so what I need the display to become is:

```
COMPANY | PAYDUE | DATEDUE
Comp 1  | 14000  | 4/30/2015   <- from- 8000+6000 
Comp 1  | 12000  | 5/15/2015   <- from- 7000+5000   
Comp 2  | 6000   | 4/30/2015   <- from- 4000+2000   
Comp 2  | 4000   | 5/15/2015   <- from- 3000+1000
```

I don't know how to add the ones that have matching `COMPANY` and `DATEDUE`. Can anyone suggest methods for this?

Also forgot to mention I was hoping to do this all in a query, but if there's no way to do this within a query I'll be happy with any solution.

**FINAL WORKING QUERY**

```
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT  " + " _id, " + colCompClass + "," + colName + ", SUM(" + colPayDue + ") AS " + colPayDue + "," + colDateDue + " FROM " + viewComps + " WHERE " + colDateDue + "=" + "( SELECT MIN (" + colDateDue + ") FROM " + viewComps + " WHERE " + colDateDue + ">=?)" + " GROUP BY " + colDateDue + "," + colCompClass, params);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this query should do it:

```
Select c.Company, sum(p.paydue), p.datedue
from company c, payments p 
where
c.company = p.company
group by p.datedue, c.company
```

**UPDATE:**

According to the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html) sqlite has aggregate functions, I have never tried in Android but I do tried in an sqlitemanager and it worked fine.
About this `c.company = p.company`, you need a way to know what payment is for what company, I assume the company table is describing the companies, and the payment table is describing the payments and has one column that specifies the company that the payment belongs to.

I re-read your question, so, from the view should be like this:

```
Select v.Company, sum(v.paydue), v.datedue
from CompanyPaymentView v
where
group by v.datedue, v.company
```

Comment: I've tried using the sum function you mentioned but ran into an error. I posted in an edit, did I do something wrong? I also need a little clarification on the `c.company = p.company` area. Where do I get `p.company`, my p table doesn't have a `company` column.

Comment: Also on a side note I read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29414170/sqlite-how-to-sum-the-values-of-column-in-gridview) that sqlite doesn't have core any function for adding columns, was this answer wrong?

Comment: Thank you for the heads up, for some reason I wasn't notified of the edit before. Got it to work with some minor adjustments, mostly little syntax errors on my end. I'll put up the working query up in an edit. Thanks again!