# Postgresql: sum of count and one column?

Tags: postgresql

I have a `user_stats` table. One of the columns in the table is `driving_time`.

```
user_stats
- user_id (FK)
- driving_time (Int)
- is_new_drive Bool
- is_time_duration Bool
```

Every time a user drives a new row is created and the `is_new_drive` is set to true.
Every time a user ends a drive a new row is created with `is_time_duration` set to true and the `driving_time` set to the amount of seconds driven.

I want to run a query that returns:

```
drives_and_duration_total | user_id
```

`drives_and_duration_total` is the sum of counting all drives for a user and the amount of time driven for the user. So I want one number that is the sum of the number of `is_new_drive` == true records plus the sum of the `driving_time` column for a given user.

So, if user 10 drove 25 times and the sum of all the `driving_time` for the user is 23034 then the `drives_and_duration_total` should be **23059** (23034+25).

What query could allow me to get that type of table as a result (I would **group by user_id**...).

I've looked at this question:

[How to compute the sum of multiple columns in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15719557/how-to-compute-the-sum-of-multiple-columns-in-postgresql)

but, I am not sure if and how this would lead me to the answer I need because I am not just computing the sum of columns, I am in need to compute the sum of one column and count the number of rows for `is_new_drive=true` case and then get the total...

Answer (score 0):

The referenced question asks and answers how to compute the sum of columns in the same row. This is not what you need instead you need the [sum function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-aggregate.html). This computes the sum of values in the column. So:

```
select user_id, sum(driving_time) + 25 as drive_minuets
  from user_stats 
 group by user_id 
 where is_time_duration;
```

Comment: So, I would need to use the dynamic row count instead of the hardcoded value 25. How would I do that?